# difficulty to maintain the value of variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, global-variables

i have written two separate function in javascript and i hava created a global variable.
first function is set the value of global variable and the second function is used that global variable to check the condition but it doesn't work.

here is my code.

```
var flag = 1;

function setSelection(){

    for (index=0; index < top.parent.frmRadio.view.length; index++) {
        if (top.parent.frmRadio.view[index].checked) {
            var radioValue = top.parent.frmRadio.view[index].value;

            if(radioValue == "graph"){
                flag = 1;
                top.parent.test2.innerHTML = flag;
            }
            else{
                flag = 0;
                top.parent.test2.innerHTML = flag;

            }

        }
    }
}


function setFileName(name){
    var fileName = name;
//  document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = fileName;
    document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = flag;
    if(flag == 1){
        top.parent.frame2.location = fileName;
        document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = fileName;
    }
    else{
        top.parent.frame2.location = "simpletree.html";
        document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = "simpletree.html";
    }


//  parent.frame2.location = fileName;
}
```

both the function are called by different place. first method is called when radio button is clicked and second when list is clicked.

Comment: *"but it won't work"* Won't work ***how***? What result do you expect? What result do you get instead? Do you see any errors in the JavaScript console? What do you see when you walk through it with a debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your global variable is fine (to the extent that global variables are fine; strongly recommend avoiding them).

I think the problem is in the `setFileName` function, you have some very odd-looking operations there. Some comments:

```
function setFileName(name){
    var fileName = name;
//  document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = fileName;
    document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = flag;
//  ^-- Do you *really* have an element on the page with the id="body"?
//      This will not change the `body` element of the page (unless you've given it that id).
    if(flag == 1){
        top.parent.frame2.location = fileName;
        document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = fileName;
//      ^--- This will replace the content of the element with id="body" with
//           the text of the filename (it will not retrieve the file)
    }
    else{
        top.parent.frame2.location = "simpletree.html";
        document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = "simpletree.html";
//      ^--- This will replace the contents of the element with id="body"
//           with the text "simpletree.html", it will not retrieve the file
    }


//  parent.frame2.location = fileName;
}
```

Setting the `innerHTML` of an element changes its contents to the actual text you assign. It doesn't load a page and put the page's content there. For that, you'd have to use an `iframe` or use ajax to load the page content (from a server on the same origin) and then assign the resulting text/markup.

Comment: i am using this "innerHTML" only for checking that it is getting right input

Comment: @Ashish: And the other points? In particular, do you really have an element with the `id` "body"?

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder  yes i have but that is only for test purpose when it will work fine then i will remove it.